# Is comma required here: "Their closest relatives the zebras and horses are mammals."?

Tags: punctuation

I found this sentence in one paper. I think one, or even two commas should be there:

> Their closest relatives, the zebras and horses are mammals.

or

> Their closest relatives, the zebras and horses, are mammals.

"*the zebras and horses*" is the noun modifier, and should be delimited with commas. Am I right? Which variant is most correct? Do missing commas in general make sentences ungrammatical?

Answer (score 2):

I would call "zebras and horses" a parenthetical phrase (although I'm not sure of what type). You don't need the definite article (but you can use it if you like), and you are right about the commas:

> Their closest relatives, zebras and horses, are mammals.

Comment: Alternatively, “their closest relatives” is a participial modifier with its copular participle implied, and the rest is a simple clause: “[Being] their closest relatives, zebras and horses are mammals”. That would make more sense with a disjunctive coordinator, though, like ‘though’.